# Prettier 'Ignored unknown option"

Tags: prettier

I'm getting this warning for multiple prettier options, even though I'm calling via npx (ie: latest version of prettier) and the options are in the documentation. Why?

```
npx prettier "**/*" --write --ignore-unknown --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern
```

...

```
[warn] Ignored unknown option --ignore-unknown.
[warn] Ignored unknown option --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern.
```

Comment: Try updating your prettier version. Version `2.1.2` gave me that warning and I removed it by updating it to version `2.8.1`

Answer (score 4):

This turned out to be some version weirdness caused by a prettier plugin in a yarn workspace package (when I did `npx prettier -v` I got a really old version).

I ended up putting prettier in `nohoist`, which did the trick.

Comment: FYI, I also got that error in a yarn workspace, after removing `nodeLinker: node-modules` from the `.yarnrc` file, and therefore using Yarn's default "pnp" mode. Cf https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#nodeLinker